# Yii2: How do you use named parameters in console commands?

Tags: php, console, yii2, named-parameters

How can I write the console command `yii controller/action --param1=something --param2=anything` and retrieve those named parameters in the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the documentation does say how to, but instead of calling it "named parameters" as I expected it to, it is called options: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#create-command

The docs is not quite complete though. So here is an example:

1. You add the parameters as properties to the controller:

```php
class CustomerController extends Controller {
    public $param1;
    public $param2;
    ...
```

2. You add the `options` method to the controller:

```php
    public function options($actionID) {
        return array_merge(parent::options($actionID), ['param1', 'param2']);
    }
```

`$actionID` must be specified, and `parent::options($actionID)` is used to include any existing options.

3. You can now access the parameters within your action with `$this->param1` and `$this->param2`, eg.:

```php
    public function actionSomething() {
        doAnything($this->param1, $this->param2);
    }
```

It's okay to combine non-named and named parameters. The named ones just need to be specified last.

Also lacking from the docs is the fact that if you specify a parameter without a value (eg. `--param1` instead of `--param1=500`) the value of `$this->param1` will be boolean `true`. If not specified at all the value will be `NULL`.

Comment: why not just call `parent::options($actionID)` instead of `Controller::options($actionID)`. You're opening yourself to a world of hurt like this if you ever refactor code.

Comment: Didn't think of that! But of course that's a better way to do it. Have adjusted answer.