# Yii2: How to pass named parameters in console command to another action?

Tags: php, controller, yii2, named-parameters

I'm running the following console command:

`yii t/gen 520 34 -someoption --number=1`

and since `t/gen` this is just an alias to the actual action `template/generate-preview` I need to pass it on, or redirect,  to another controller/action. So I do this:

```php
Yii::$app->runAction('template/generate-preview', [ $ID, $count ]);
```

So the numbers 520 and 34 are passed on but how do I pass on the named parameters `someoption` and `number`? They are options in the actual controller and therefore public properties of that controller (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38812711/2404541)).

Is it possible pass on those named parameters, that is, set those properties on the controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use key-value pairs in parameters list:

```
Yii::$app->runAction('template/generate-preview', [
    $ID,
    $count,
    'someoption' => true,
    'number' => 1
]);
```

And do not add `--` prefixes to parameters names, they will be prepended automatically.